# MySQLi is loaded in PHP cli but not in apache?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, mysqli

I am running PHP version 5.5.9 on an Ubuntu VM set up using Vagrant/Puppet.

If I run the following code in php-cli

```
if (!extension_loaded('mysqli')) { echo 'Not loaded'; } else { echo 'Loaded'; }
```

I get a 'loaded' repsonse, indicating mysqli is loaded.

However, if I run the same code in apache2, I get a not loaded response.

I can't see any difference in the two php.ini, and I haven't modified either. I have restarted apache2 since I ran `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`. Running `phpinfo();` in both apache2 and cli both show `mysqli`.

Does anyone have any idea as to why it wouldn't be loaded in apache2 and how I can load it?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-php-to-check-if-the-mysqli-library-has-been-installed/5671

Comment: @Terminus Same issue, loaded in CLI but not in Apache2.

Comment: Have you tried just using some functions from the mysqli_ library? Just to see what happens?

Comment: @Terminus I first recognized the issue as I was getting a 500 internal server error when trying to instantiate a mysqli object with `$dbConn = new mysqli(.....);`.

I was able to pull data from the database using `mysqli` in CLI.

Comment: gotcha. Sorry, no clue :(

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: @Feint, so did you figure this out?

Comment: @mrun Haha, yes. It's quite embarrassing really - I had set up a static IP for my Vagrant box however accessing that IP was actually hitting my host boxes files, and my host machine doesn't have PHP installed.

I set up port-forwarding on 8080 => 80 and that allowed me to access my VM which works fine.